# How to avoid repeating the same $.ajax() call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two $.ajax() calls in my javascript code.

```
    $.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost/webmap201/php/load_data.php',
          data: {
            tbl: 'district'
          },
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(response) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(response));
            json_district = JSON.parse(response);
            district = L.geoJSON(json_district, {
              onEachFeature: return_district,
            });
            ctl_layers.addOverlay(district, "district", "Overlays");
            ar_district_object_names.sort();
            $("#text_district_find_project").autocomplete({
              source: ar_district_object_names,
            });
    
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Error: " + error);
          }
    
        }
    
      );


  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/webmap201/php/load_data.php',
      data: {
        tbl: 'province'
      },
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(response));
        json_province = JSON.parse(response);
        province = L.geoJSON(json_province, {
          onEachFeature: return_province,
        });
        ctl_layers.addOverlay(province, "province", "Overlays");
        ar_province_object_names.sort();
        $("#text_province_find_project").autocomplete({
          source: ar_province_object_names,
        });

      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert("Error: " + error);
      }

    }

  );
```

changes on both ajax are as below:

```
tbl: 'district' -> tbl: 'province'
json_district -> json_province
return_district -> return_province
(district, "district", "Overlays") -> (province, "province", "Overlays")
ar_district_object_names -> ar_province_object_names
$("#text_district_find_project") ->  $("#text_province_find_project")
```

Is there a way I can call this $.ajax() inside a function with one parameter and call the function afterwards. As an example:

```
function lyr(shpName){
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/webmap201/php/load_data.php',
      data: {
        tbl: `${shpName}`
      },
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(response));
        json_shpName = JSON.parse(response);
        shpName = L.geoJSON(json_shpName, {
          onEachFeature: return_shpName,
        });
        ctl_layers.addOverlay(shpName, `${shpName}`, "Overlays");
        ar_shpName_object_names.sort();
        $("#text_shpName_find_project").autocomplete({
          source: ar_shpName_object_names,
        });

      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert("Error: " + error);
      }

    }
    
    );
  }
  
  lyr (district);
```

Can I use template strings? Can I use that a function inside a function. Any help would be highly appriceated.

Comment: You can only using string literals if running on ES6 compliant browsers. See https://caniuse.com/template-literals

Comment: If you don't care about scoping, you can assign your method to window.lyr = function (shpName) {$.jax....} and call it wherever you want.

Comment: @Rorchackh So using 'json_shpName' instead of 'json_district' within the function would work? I mean how to substitute 'shpName' with in the 'json_shpName' with the 'district'?  I want varibale  json_shpName to become json_district. Is that possible? Am I getting clear to you... So sorry if I'm confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for ajax call.
For eg.:-

```js
function serviceajaxjson(_successfun, _failurefun, _url, _data, _async, _global) {
    if (_successfun == null) _successfun = ajax_return_successfun;
    if (_failurefun == null) _failurefun = ajax_return_failurefun;
    if (_global != false) { _global = true; }
    if (_async != false) { _async = true; }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: _url,
        data: _data,
        global: _global,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        async: _async,
        success: _successfun,
        error: ajax_return_error,
        failure: _failurefun
    });
}
function ajax_return_successfun(response) {
    console.info("success for " + response.d);
}
function ajax_return_failurefun(response) {
    console.error("failuer occoured for " + response);
}
function ajax_return_error(response) {
    console.warn("error occoured for " + response);
}


// // // call the above function


function myResponseFn(response){
  if(response.data){
    // // your code...
  }
}
var data = "{'tbl': 'district'}";
serviceajaxjson(myResponseFn,myResponseFn,"http://localhost/webmap201/php/load_data.php",data);
```

Comment: Is there anyway we can change all the 'district' or 'province' into another word using a function? 
`tbl: 'district' -> tbl: 'example'`
`json_district -> json_example`
`return_district -> return_example`
`(district, "district", "Overlays") -> (example, "example", "Overlays")`
`ar_district_object_names -> ar_example_object_names`
`$("#text_district_find_project") ->  $("#text_example_find_project")`

Comment: use below hit for  district ;- 

`var data = "{'tbl': 'district'}";
serviceajaxjson(myResponseFn,myResponseFn,"http://localhost/webmap201/php/load_data.php",data);`

and for province:-

`var data = "{'tbl': 'province'}";
serviceajaxjson(myResponseFn,myResponseFn,"http://localhost/webmap201/php/load_data.php",data);`       


You need to change just the data variable..

Comment: This is the simplest you can do. And you can use the `serviceajaxjson()` function for other ajax calls also..... @Hashanhemachandra

Answer (score 0):

If you're using latest version of popular browser (IE's dead, use Edge instead), then the simplest answer is yes. You might need some tweaking on the parameters and its use, but it should work